# Spring Root Context created twice

Tags: java, spring

My applications is a microservice that I compile into war and deploy to Wildfly 12 (mostly out of convenience - I don't use web context at all). I use "vanilla" spring with xml config. Once my application starts I can see in the logs, that all beans are created twice. It also seems like those duplicated beans get destroyed at some point in time for seemingly no reason.

The web.xml contains only this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Most of the answers for the similar questions were mentioning that spring automatically picks up configurations if the filename contains servlet's name, but it's not like this in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was caused by a following line in config.xml:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="(...)"/>
```

After removing the lines, all the beans are injected only ones and context is not getting destroyed.